How to join multiple tables and divide the metrics over the output rows?
I am using Google Big Query to join multiple tables. The three tables I am joining look as follows:
Table A



brand
searchterm




ford
ford


ford
foord


peugeot
peugeot



Table B



label
searchterm




brand
brand


generic
generic



Table C



date
campaign_name
clicks




01-01-2024
brand - ford
30


01-01-2024
brand - ford - peugeot
50



The goal of the query is to add the brand and label information from table A and B to table C. The joining should be done on the campaign_name and the searchterm columns. When a searchterm exisits in the campaign_name, the corresponing brand or label is added in the output. Currently I have this query set up:
WITH brands AS (
  SELECT 
  brand,
  CONCAT('%',searchterm,'%') AS searchterm
  FROM Table A
),

labels AS (
  SELECT 
  label,
  CONCAT('%',searchterm,'%') AS searchterm
  FROM Table B
),

FINAL AS (
  SELECT 
  date,
  campaign_name,
  CASE WHEN LOWER(campaign_name) LIKE brands.searchterm THEN brands.brand_name ELSE 'generic' END AS brand,
  CASE WHEN LOWER(campaign_name) LIKE labels.searchterm THEN labels.label ELSE 'no label' END AS label, 
  SUM(clicks) AS clicks,
  FROM Table C`
  LEFT JOIN brands
  ON LOWER(campaign_name) LIKE brands.searchterm 
  LEFT JOIN labels
  ON LOWER(campaign_name) LIKE labels.searchterm
  WHERE 1=1 
  GROUP BY date, campaign_name, brand, label)

SELECT * FROM FINAL

This query gives the correct output when there is one match between campaign_name and searchterm. However if there are multiple matches, like in the second row of table C, there should be other output. In that case the value for clicks should be divided by the amount of matches and distributed over the rows. The desired output from combining table A, B and C should look as follows:



date
campaign_name
brand
label
clicks




01-01-2024
brand - ford
ford
brand
30


01-01-2024
brand - ford - peugeot
ford
brand
25


01-01-2024
brand - ford - peugeot
peugeot
brand
25



The value for 'clicks' has been divided by 2 and attributed to both brands ford as well as peugeot. How would I achieve such output?
I have used different approaches to solve this problem and the current status of the query is in the description. I tried dividing the clicks metric by some value but I can not figure out which value to divide by.

What is "merk" in "GROUP BY date, campaign_name, merk, label"?

"merk" should be "brand", missed it when translating the query to post here. I edited the original question

Can you try this ?
with TableA as (
          select "ford" as brand,"ford" as searchterm
union all select "ford" as brand, "foord" as searchterm
union all select "peugeot" as brand, "peugeot" as searchterm
union all select "peugeot" as brand, "peugeoot" as searchterm
),

TableB as (
          select "brand" as label,"brand" as searchterm
union all select "generic" as brand, "generic" as searchterm
),

TableC as(
          select '01-01-2024' as date,"brand - ford" as campaign_name, 30 as clicks
union all select '01-01-2024' as date,"brand - ford - peugeot" as campaign_name, 50 as clicks
union all select '01-01-2024' as date,"brand - ford - peugeot - foord" as campaign_name, 30 as clicks
),

brands AS (
  SELECT 
  brand,
  CONCAT('%',searchterm,'%') AS searchterm
  FROM tableA
),

labels AS (
  SELECT 
  label,
  CONCAT('%',searchterm,'%') AS searchterm
  FROM tableB
),


FINAL AS (
  SELECT 
  date,
  campaign_name,
  CASE WHEN LOWER(campaign_name) LIKE brands.searchterm THEN brands.brand ELSE 'generic' END AS brand,
  CASE WHEN LOWER(campaign_name) LIKE labels.searchterm THEN labels.label ELSE 'no label' END AS label, 
  clicks AS clicks,
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY campaign_name) as match_count,
  FROM tableC
  LEFT JOIN brands
  ON LOWER(campaign_name) LIKE brands.searchterm 
  LEFT JOIN labels
  ON LOWER(campaign_name) LIKE labels.searchterm
  WHERE 1=1 
  GROUP BY date, campaign_name, brand, label,clicks)


SELECT * EXCEPT (clicks,match_count), clicks/match_count as newClicks FROM FINAL

I have removed the sum for clicks as it adds the total clicks to the table and also used the match_count as the number to divide the clicks to the joined table.

